# why I am getting this error while deploying an app?

Tags: kotlin, heroku, ktor

I where currently making **IoT** project with [ktor](https://ktor.io) (a kotlin library used to create apis).I am able to deploy it in my machine smoothly but after I deployed it in heroku it start getting error

**What I have tried**

I have packed my propject as fat jar file using shadowJar
then I added `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/Server.jar` procfile

it start showing

```sh
2020-12-05T16:25:00.375911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
path="/test" host=bot-project-server.herokuapp.com request_id=a757b03c-3511-4075-86d2-c29fc7f58672
fwd="196.188.177.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

then I typed `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a $My_App` nothing have changed neither

after 1.30 mins another error

`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch`

**My last attempt**

i have changed from `web` **=>** `worker` in Procfile this have no that much effect just removed `Error R10` in the above ^

**My Code**

```kotlin
fun main(){
    /**main*/
    val mPort = System.getProperty("PORT")?.toInt() ?: 23567
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = mPort){
            doPost()
        }.start(true)
}
fun Application.doPost() {
    routing {
        get("/test"){
            this.call.respondText("Done!")
        }
    }
}
```

*Note*: The same jar file that I deployed worked in my machine smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers):

> The port to bind to is assigned by Heroku as the PORT environment variable.

The problem is that you use the wrong method to get the value of an environment variable `PORT`. You should use `System.getenv` instead of `System.getProperty`.

Overall I did the following steps to successfully deploy an application:

1. Created a fat jar using the [ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin.
2. Used steps described in [deploying Executable JAR files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files#using-the-heroku-java-cli-plugin) documentation article to deploy jar into Heroku application.